# How to access 18-character ID in Visualforce page without using a custom controller

Tags: apex, visualforce

A while ago I built a custom controller before I knew how the platform worked completely (not that I do now, but I digress). Anyway, the controller was supplying the 18-character ID of the object that was being accessed. Now, I know I can just pull the ID out of the standard controller and dump my custom controller entirely, but it's only supplying the 15-character ID. How can I access the 18-character ID without the custom controller in the Visualforce page? Is there a formula I can use? Or does the standard controller provide a property that is the 18-character ID?

Here's how my current Visualforce page is like:

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" extensions="vNextAttachmentsController">
    <apex:iframe height="200" scrolling="true" src="https://{host}/{!$User.Id}/Attachments/Opportunity/{!Id}" />
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you can use the [CASESAFEID function](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000005288&language=en_US) to covert from 15 to 18 char ids..

but i believe visualforce / standard controller by default will give you the 18 char ids..

in the below code you will get the 18 char id for both the options

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" >

{!Account.Id}

{!CASESAFEID(Account.Id)}

</apex:page>
```

Comment: Perfect! It turns out that `{!Id}` by itself returns the 15-character ID, but `{!OBJECT.Id}` returns the 18-character ID I need. That's where I was having issues because I never qualified the lookup with the object name. Thanks for the help!